# How to correctly query OData with filter in nested type based on property from parent type?

Tags: odata

I am getting a dynamic value (_FilterDate) on the parent type that I want to use as a filter for the nested type `/Trips` but can't get it to work because I still get entries in the nested data that do not meet the filter. Actually, there is no difference whether I use this filter or not.

```
$filter=Trips/all(d:d/EndDate ge _FilterDate)
```

I also tried this:

```
$expand=Trips($filter=EndDate ge $it/_FilterDate)
```

but got the error: "Could not find a property named '_FilterDate' on type 'Default.Trips'."

So I'm wondering how to get the syntax right and thus kindly ask for help.

**Example portion:**

```
"value": [
       {
           "_FilterCompany": "YES",
           "_FilterLocation": "YES",
           "_FilterDate": "2020-01-08",
           "Trips": [
               {
                   "StartDate": "2019-06-24",
                   "EndDate": "2019-06-28",
               },
               {
                   "StartDate": "2020-02-07",
                   "EndDate": "2020-02-07",
               }         
                     ]
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues going on here:

> this response is specifically regarding the OData v4 specification and the .Net ODataLib implementation.

1. You have correctly identified that when filtering results based on a nested collection you you must separately apply the filter within that collection if you want the fitler to apply to the items within that collection as well.

   - This is because the root level `$filter` criteria only affects the selection of the root items, think of it as if the `$expand` operator is applied after the `$filter` has identified the top level of row the return, `$expand` is simply executed as a *Linq* `Include` statement.
2. In your second attempt, `$it` references the instance of `Trips`, which is a known bug/by design, according to the spec it is expected to work the way you have implemented it:

   > [5.1.1.6.4 $it](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-os-part2-url-conventions.html#_Toc372793855)
   >   *Example 82: customers along with their orders that shipped to the same city as the customer's address. The nested filter expression is evaluated in the context of Orders; $it allows referring to values in the outer context of Customers.*
   >
   > ```
   > http://host/service/Customers?
   >     $expand=Orders($filter=$it/Address/City eq ShipTo/City)
   > ```

   So knowing the $it is broken, the spec doc does specify a `$root` identifier that you might also be able to use, but in ODataLib 7.3 `$root` is still not supported OOTB either. There is an issue logged here: [$it references the wrong resource #616](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/616)

## Workaround

If your `Trips` data type has a navigation property back to the *Filter*/root record, then you can use that navigation property as part of the $filter:

> Assuming the navigation property is called `Filter`

```
$filter=Trips/all(d:d/EndDate ge _FilterDate)&$expand=Trips($filter=EndDate ge Filter/_FilterDate)
```

If your `Trips` type does not have this navigation link back to the parent record then you are stuck at this stage with these two workarounds:

1. Create a `Function` on the controller to return this filtered data specifically, as this would be simple to evaluate as a `Linq` query in the *server-side*.
2. Accept that the server will return extra rows in the Trips collections, and apply the filter over the results in the *client-side*.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm afraid I cannot set navigation, that comes as default ("value" for first level) so i will just have to accept the extra rows at least until the $it bugfix is ready.